# Angular asynchronous request not loaded in time

Tags: angular, asynchronous, frontend

I am experiencing some issues with a tricky asynchronous request I am trying to perform in Angular. I am displaying a user interface with specific information condensed in a table. The table contains headers that are loaded from a backend using a `http.get` method provided by the `HttpClient` module. I call this method in the `ngOnInit()` method. Occasionally, it occurs that the table's headers are not loaded before the table is displayed. How can this problem be avoided?

Some information to the implementation:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.toastService.reset();
    this.load();
  }

  load(): void {
    const workflows = this.getWorkflows();
    const headers = this.getHeaders();

    forkJoin([workflows, headers]).subscribe((results) => {
      this.setWorkflows(results[0]);
      this.setHeaders(results[1]);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(`error = ${error}`);
    });
  }

  getWorkflows(): Observable<VisibleWorkflow[]> {
    return this.workflowService.getWorkflows().pipe(
      map((response) => {
        return this.workflows = response;
      })
    );
  }

  setWorkflows(workflows: VisibleWorkflow[]): void {
    this.workflows = workflows.map((workflow) => {
      return {...workflow};
    });
  }

  getHeaders(): Observable<VisibleHeader[]> {
    return this.headerService.getHeaders().pipe(
      map((response) => {
        return this.headers = response;
      })
    );
  }

  setHeaders(headers: VisibleHeader[]): void {
    this.headers = headers;
  }
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: you can use `concateMap()` for processing http request sequentially .

Comment: how you are creating table? using ngFor? please share screen of html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing results from the point that you're assigning the values to `this.workflows` and `this.headers` twice. At first, you're assigning a value inside of the `RxJS.map` operators and after that in the subscription of your `forkJoin`.

Since `forkJoin` only emits the values as soon every Observable completes you should assign the values only in the subscription and not in `RxJS.map`.

So, your code would look something like following:

```js
load(): void {
  const workflows = this.getWorkflows();
  const headers = this.getHeaders();

  forkJoin([workflows, headers]).subscribe(
    // I used array deconstruction here because I prefer that over hard coded indexes
    ([wfs, heads]) => {
      this.setWorkflows(wfs);
      this.setHeaders(heads);
    }, 
    (error) => {
      console.error(`error = ${error}`);
    }
  );
}

getWorkflows(): Observable<VisibleWorkflow[]> {
  return this.workflowService.getWorkflows();
}

getHeaders(): Observable<VisibleHeader[]> {
  return this.headerService.getHeaders();
}
```

Like this you're only assigning the values as soon as both requests have been completed, so you shouldn't have a timing issue anymore.

You could also consider to hide your table as long as both variables aren't set:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="headers?.length && workflows">
  <!-- Your table here -->
</ng-container>
```

This would also solve a timing issue, if existing ;)

Comment: This seemed to solve the trick! I did not notice that I was setting the values twice. Thank you Batajus!

Answer (score 0):

You can use combineLatest

combineLatest: Whenever any input Observable emits a value, it computes a formula using the latest values from all the inputs, then emits the output of that formula. https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest